# iterating over json fieldsnames

Tags: java, json, eclipse, iterator, jackson

I have to iterate over a json file on its fields. I am using jackson library. My Json file looks like that:

```
  {"type":"item","id":"Q1","labels":{"en":{"language":"en","value":"universe"},"fr":{"language":"fr","value":"Univers"},"la":{"language":"la","value":"universum"},"uz":{"language":"uz","value":"Olam"},"ru":{"language":"ru","value":"\u0432\u0441\u0435\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043d\u0430\u044f"},"pl":{"language":"pl","value":"wszech\u015bwiat"},"nb":{"language":"nb","value":"universet"},"eo":{"language":"eo","value":"universo"},"it":{"language":"it","value":"universo"},"es":{"language":"es","value":"universo"},"de":{"language":"de","value":"Universum"},"ca":{"language":"ca","value":"univers"},"en-gb":{"language":"en-gb","value":"universe"},"de-ch":{"language":"de-ch","value":"Universum"}"}]},"claims":{"P1036":[{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P1036","datavalue":{"value":"113","type":"string"},"datatype":"string"},"
```

I tried the following code in order to do it:(The parser starts after the "type" token)

```
while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        String fieldName = parser.getCurrentName();
        System.out.print("\niFieldName is "+parser.getCurrentName());
    }
```

I have got the follwing order:

```
FieldName is id
FieldName is labels
FieldName is labels
FieldName is en
FieldName is en
FieldName is language
FieldName is language
FieldName is value
FieldName is value
```

While the order I am trying to echieve is:

```
FieldName is id
FieldName is labels
FieldName is Claims
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

the json string is invalid

```
 {"type":"item",
  "id":"Q1",
   "labels":{
    "en":{"language":"en","value":"universe"},
    "fr":{"language":"fr","value":"Univers"},
    "la":{"language":"la","value":"universum"},
    "uz":{"language":"uz","value":"Olam"},
    "ru":{"language":"ru","value":"\u0432\u0441\u0435\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043d\u0430\u044f"},
    "pl":{"language":"pl","value":"wszech\u015bwiat"},
    "nb":{"language":"nb","value":"universet"},
    "eo":{"language":"eo","value":"universo"},
    "it":{"language":"it","value":"universo"},
    "es":{"language":"es","value":"universo"},
    "de":{"language":"de","value":"Universum"},
    "ca":{"language":"ca","value":"univers"},
    "en-gb":{"language":"en-gb","value":"universe"},
    "de-ch":{"language":"de-ch","value":"Universum"}
    "}]}, <-- ???
   "claims":{
    "P1036":[
     {"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P1036","datavalue":{"value":"113","type":"string"},"datatype":"string"}," <-- ???
```